# Replacing openssl-0.9.8zf with openssl-0.9.8zg causes problems

Tags: c, ssl, openssl

I am working on a product where its built in two steps:

Step 1:
openssl-0.9.8zf is added as includes for compiling the product, and uses ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll (of the same version) for linking.

Step 2:
While packaging the product, the above mentioned dlls are replaced with openssl-0.9.8zg version's and openssl.exe file is also added to support another library which loads that in at run time.

However this method is causing problems on which I am not able to lay a finger on. It works perfectly when I use the same version in Step 1 and Step 2. Given that openssl-0.9.8zg is 100% compatible with openssl-0.9.8zf, and that they are dynamically loaded, are there any guesses on what can cause problems?

OpenSSL information on versions: http://abi-laboratory.pro/tracker/timeline/openssl/

Comment: What specific problems does it cause?

Comment: The library which loads openssl.exe has a function call which initiates SSL connection and it fails at that point.

Comment: Please share any error message in the problem description above.

Comment: That's the best information I have.

Comment: Which particular function of OpenSSL causes the problem in your case? We can look at the changes in the code.